# In maven, how to know what dependency to add from a import command

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to create a maven project of code from internet.
I met with some import lines in the code, like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorProtocol;
```

And have the error message:

> Cannot resolve symbole 'hbase'

I add some dependencies to the pom file, but it doesn't work.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I know what exactly I have to import?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Go to [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/) and just search for the class you are looking for.

I have just searched for your `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter`, and the results are [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter), it shows all the jars that have this file(mostly it will be same package with different versions).

You actually had to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this link really helps!